# foreach, unexpected result for element, which key is 0

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have this code

```
$arr = array(
    "0"=>"http://site.com/somepage/param1/param2/0",
    "1"=>"http://site.com/somepage/param1/param2/1",
    "thispage" => "http://site.com/somepage/param1/param2/2",
    "3"=> "http://site.com/somepage/param1/param2/3"
);



foreach ($arr as $k=>$v) {
    if ($k == "thispage") {
        echo $k." ";
    }
    else {
        echo '<a href="'.$v.'">'.$k.'</a> ';
    }
}
```

Its surprise, for first element `"0"=>"http://site.com/somepage/param1/param2/0",` not created link, (for other elements works fine)

If replace first element key `0` on something other, for example `4`, now links created. What is wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because `0 == "thispage"` and the first key is `0`. To find out more about this, take a look at the PHP manual page about [Type Juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php).

Use `===` ("is identical to") instead of `==` ("is equal to"), because `0` is *equal* to `"thispage"`, but not *identical*.

This is what happens with `==`:

- `$key` takes the `integer` value of `0`
- PHP tries to compare `0 == "thispage"`
- in order to make the comparison, it needs to cast `"thispage"` to `integer`
- the resulting comparison is `0 == 0`, which is `true`

If you use `===`:

- `$key` takes the `integer` value of `0`
- PHP tries to compare `0 === "thispage"`
- since `0` is of a different type (`integer`) than `"thispage"` (`string`), the result is `false`

Answer (score 2):

Do the:

```
if ($k === "thispage")
```

You have to use **identical comparison operator** `===` as **equal comparison operator** won't help here, because

> If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves
>   numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the
>   comparison performed numerically.

`thispage` converted to number will return `0`, so your if statement will match if you use equal comparison operator `==`. When you do identical comparison `===` if type does not match it returns false.

You can read about comparison operators [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

Answer (score 2):

This is What you are doing wrong.

```
if ($k === "thispage") {
    echo .$k." ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if ($k === "thispage") {
        echo $k." ";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php:

> A key may be either an integer or a string. **If a key is the standard representation of an integer, it will be interpreted as such** (i.e. "8" will be interpreted as 8, while "08" will be interpreted as "08").

So in your case Stings `"1", "2" and "3"` are treated as integers.

To fix this use the `===` operator that check for type along with value.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the result you see is the comparison operator you use. == is too imprecise sometimes and can result in wierd things like this. Using the === will compare the values for exactness and will prevent the issue you have.

so:

```
foreach ($arr as $k=>$v) {
    // this is the important thing
    if ($k === "thispage") {
        echo $k." ";
    }
    else {
        echo '<a href="'.$v.'">'.$k.'</a> ';
    }
}
```